# Bootstrap popover style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

is there a way how to style the popover window from boostrap? 
DEMO below:

```
<body>
<script> $(function () { $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover() }) </script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="This should be styled">Button</button>
</body>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/97tmrqf0/1/

What I want to do: make that popup window have this HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <span data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close">
            </span>Výbava vozidla</span>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>LOKÁTOR/KAMERA</li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>SPORTOVNÍ SEDADLA</li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>ALARM</li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>UPEVN DĚT-SEDAČKY</li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>TAŽNÉ ZAŘÍZENÍ ODNÍM</li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>SPORTOVNÍ DIFERENC</li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>DISKY 8,5 J X 18 ALU</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>                        
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default template for a popover is:

```
<div class="popover" role="tooltip">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title"></h3>
    <div class="popover-content"></div>
</div>
```

So you can just add some CSS that targets these elements.

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: So is there a way how to make give it HTML in my question? :)

Comment: @Andurit If you set the html option to true the content will be inserted as HTML rather than text. And you could combine this with the template option to edit the entire template. See the linked documentation for a full list of options.

Answer (score 1):

add these css to change style of popover, this is sample

```
h3.popover-title {
color: green;
background: yellow;
}
.popover-content {
color: blue;
background: green;
font-size: 11px;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/97tmrqf0/2/

Comment: Cool i see you can pretty easy edit CSS, but is there a way to edit HTML as well?
Btw Thumb up!

Comment: You can change the text using the properties i.e. data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="This should be styled"

Comment: Yea i noticed i can change text but I need to add new HTML in it.(i edited my question)

Comment: In this example i have added <span> sample </span> after popover-title class using append() of jquery. http://fiddle.jshell.net/97tmrqf0/4/    sample is not a text it is a span tag added dynamically